# How to get the graphql schema during code build time (during maven/gradle build)

Tags: graphql-spqr, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

Is there a way to generate and store the graphql schema as txt file as part of the build artifacts?

Comment: I was also thinking recently that this would be useful in some scenarios. But no, there's currently nothing out-of-the-box to support this. Well... I do have some experimental code that works with Spring AOT and does what you want, but it's not a general solution. What _exactly_ are you trying to do and why? If I know more details maybe I can think of something.

Comment: Our team is planning to use/introduce graphql federation layer(still PoC using Apollo graphql federation server https://github.com/apollographql/federation-jvm) and they wanted versioned graphql schema file of all the sub graphs in order to build the super graph. Also our UI team wants to build the JavaScript client library using versioned static schema file.

Comment: Each subgraph will be running as  different micro service in different  host/machine. Also is there a way to achieve the same using SPQR library?

Comment: It's just occurred to me that you could always write a test that produces the schema file. It's a bit of a hack, but it does the job and requires no special plugins or anything. If using Maven, you could configure a special invocation of the surefire plugin that always runs and executes that specific "test" only. In Gradle, I assume you can just script this logic without needing anything special at all. Would that suffice?